# find and replace using grep inside jpg files

Tags: shell, ssh, grep, replace

I've been wrestling with a grep issue, in attempt to reverse a server-wide hack on my server, but grep doesn't seem to be able to search inside jpg files when run as a shell, but the grep command on it's own works file in ssh.

**this returns results fine:**
    grep -l -R "nastycode" /var/www/vhosts

**but when run as a shell script, it doesn't find the jpgs anymore.**

```
for file in $(grep -l -R "nastycode" /var/www/vhosts)
 do
  sed -e "s/"nastycode"/"nicecode"/ig" $file > /tmp/tempfile.tmp
  mv /tmp/tempfile.tmp $file
  echo "Modified: " $file
 done
```

Q: Could it be to do with the 'for file in' part?
Q: inside our search pattern "nastycode", can we search for things which have regexp chars but treat them as normal ($,|? etc)?

thanks in advance.

Nicholas

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "search inside jpg files" - you mean you want sed to somehow search for a string in a binary file (.jpg)? Re 'nastycode' being a literal string as opposed to regex -- you can use `-F` (or `--fixed-strings`).

Comment: thanks for your reply. when I say "search within JPG files", i mean that the hacker has edited the jpg file and added php code to the file, but still showing the jpg to the user. (they also a htaccess file added to process the jpg as a php and execute the code)

Comment: the literal doesn't seem to work. i'm trying to search for ") || stristr(" and replace with ") &&false || stristr(" to render the script useless

Comment: Are you saying {grep -l -R "nastycode" /var/www/vhosts} returns some jpgs, but when run in a script, that same line doesn't find the jpgs? First thing I'd check is "whcih grep" to make sure your path isn't changing.

Comment: i think you guys have helped me solve one of the problems. I can now get it to run correctly from the shell script.  the problem of not returning results I think is coming from the recursive function not looking through enough children depths, or the -F is also failing

Comment: is there a way to tell sed to treat the string as literal and not a regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` has an option to ignore special characters (`-F`) as long as there are no newlines. `sed`, unfortunately, has no such option.  If there are special characters in it, they must be escaped.  If you have a lot of `/`s in it, you can avoid having to escape them by changing the delimiter - `s|old|new|` or `s@old@new@`, or some other character your code doesn't contain. Regarding the rest of the structure, I have a couple comments. First, you should never use that `for file in command` structure, it will break on white space; use `**` (you may need to enable it with `shopt -s globstar` first) or `find` instead. Next, GNU `sed` has an inline option, `-i`. You can also specify a backup suffix for it (`-i.bak`, for instance). As `sed` only changes if it finds a pattern, there's really no reason to use `grep` to limit the files anyway.

Putting those all together, (once you get your regex escaped - we can help with that too if you need it) you can use these:

```
# Globstar
for file in /var/www/vhosts/**; do
    sed -i.bak 's/) || stristr(\$ua/) \&\&false || stristr($ua/ig' $file
done

# find
find /var/www/vhosts -type f -exec sed -i.bak 's/) || stristr(\$ua/) \&\&false || stristr($ua/ig' {} \;

# If you really want the echo notification
find /var/www/vhosts -type f -exec grep -qiF ') || stristr($ua' {} \; -exec sed -i.bak 's/) || stristr(\$ua/) \&\&false || stristr($ua/ig' {} + -printf "Modified %p\n"
```

Comment: thanks Kevin, I come from a PHP background and not very used to doing this sort of thing, but for some reason the problem has found my desk :)  the actual code i'm looking to replace is ") || stristr($ua", and replace that with ") &&false || stristr($ua".  Could you please help me to escape that string? I notice that it doesn't preserve the ownership of files either, so when we modify the file, it changes ownership to root.

Comment: when I play with your examples, i get the error 'find: missing argument to `-exec'.  i am testing it with a plain string, just to understand it before I try the difficult search string.

Comment: @user1239330 OK, I've updated with the actual string. You only need to escape the `$` in the search and the `&`s in the replacement. Note that in the last example I didn't escape the `$` in the `grep` because I gave it the `-F` flag.

Comment: And I see I missed the `{} \;`, I've added it in.

Comment: Regarding changing ownership, are you quite sure yours is actually changing the ownership? My tests don't, and in general commands won't change ownership to root unless explicitly requested to (creating or `chown`ing a file)

Comment: wow. that's very clever Kevin. I have tried the bottom one, which works perfectly, and it keeps the permissions intact.  where's the 'buy user a beer' button?

Comment: do you find that when running the command, it takes a really long time  if we widen our search folders? maybe we could refine the query to only look inside jpg/gif files.

Comment: Kevn, the only negative things I can see from using sed/find is that every file searched for (regardless of having the search pattern) is modified, which means it would be quite time intensive to perform large searches, which would make me think the find command needs to be refined as much as possible (withfiletypes and date-modified filters) to reduce the processing time.. would that make sense?

Comment: @user1239330 The bottom one should only change the ones where the string is found (the ones where `grep -q` exits with status zero). The `sed` is run once per file. If you change the last `\;` to `+` it will only run once, with all the files. I'll update to show that.